# CodeIgniter strange behaviour with set_value

Tags: php, codeigniter, frameworks

I encountered the following problem on PHP Version 5.2.17, on my others servers (PHP 5.2.6 and PHP/5.3.10) the problem doesn’t exists!

I have a simple controller:

```
function test() 
{
  $data = array('test' => NULL);
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('test', '', 'trim|xss_clean|required');
  if ($this->form_validation->run()) {
    $data['test'] = $this->form_validation->set_value('test');
  }
  $data['result'] = array('valuebydatabase' => 'lorem');
  $this->load->view('test', $data);
}
```

A simple view:

```
<?=form_open(current_url());?>
<?php
// For debugging
echo $test;
?>

<input type="text" name="test" id="test" value="<?=set_value('test', $result['valuebydatabase']);?>">

<input type="submit" name="sbm" value="Submit" />

<?=form_close();?>
```

On my Server running PHP 5.2.17 the input value is always “lorem” although I post another value, on the other servers I get the right value…

I think PHP is initalizing a new object instead of using the existing object.
I’m debbuging now the problem on both servers and found the source of the problem:

In the form_helper.php the server tries to get a new instance:
$CI =& get_instance(); -> Alias for: CI_Controller::get_instance()

On the one server we have the rules set in this object, on the others not!

So we are now in the core file:

```
/**
 * CodeIgniter Application Controller Class
 *
 * This class object is the super class that every library in
 * CodeIgniter will be assigned to.
 *
 * @package  CodeIgniter
 * @subpackage Libraries
 * @category Libraries
 * @author  ExpressionEngine Dev Team
 * @link  http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html
 */
class CI_Controller {

 private static $instance;

 /**
  * Constructor
  */
 public function __construct()
 {
  self::$instance =& $this;

  // Assign all the class objects that were instantiated by the
  // bootstrap file (CodeIgniter.php) to local class variables
  // so that CI can run as one big super object.
  foreach (is_loaded() as $var => $class)
  {
   $this->$var =& load_class($class);
  }

  $this->load =& load_class('Loader', 'core');

  $this->load->initialize();

  log_message('debug', "Controller Class Initialized");
 }

 public static function &get;_instance()
 {
  return self::$instance;
 }
}
// END Controller class

/* End of file Controller.php */
/* Location: ./system/core/Controller.php */
```

But I have no idea why the one PHP-Version gives me with **return self::$instance;** the right object and the other one a new object?

Comment: I've had this problem too. I fixed it by using `get_instance()` explicitly instead of relying on `$this`. The worst thing about codeigniter is its CI superobject. The second worst thing is its obsession with singletons.

Comment: Thank you for your response, in which file you called get_instance() explicitly instead of relying on $this? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using

```
$this->form_validation->set_value('test');
```

To set your $data['test'] value?  Why don't you just use:

```
$data['test'] = $this->input->post('test');
```

You don't even really need to do this.  The entire point of set_value is to set the input value automatically when the form validation fails or when a value already exists for the input. So really, you don't even need the above lines in your controller.  Just placing set_value in your view will load your visitor's input value if the form validation fails.  [Check out](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html) their documentation.

Comment: When you are using just $this->input->post, your postdata pass not the xss-clean (default on), and your other rules defined in  $this->form_validation->set_rules. I know I could bypass my problem by overwriting the default value. But I wanna know why my server behaves this way and make sure that not other functions are affected.

Comment: All POST and GET inputs will be clean if you enable XSS filtering by default in your config.php

Comment: That's true, but then it's no more possible to embed a template editor etc. But I simply have the worry, that this get_instance problem affects also other libraries. And I want to figure out what is the exactly source of this problem? It works fine with an older version and a newer one, so is it my php.ini configuration or is there a bug of PHP 5.2.17?

Comment: Why is it no longer possible to embed a template editor? You mean [mustache](http://mustache.github.com/) or something? I've used it in projects before. I've also never ran into this issue before.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the correction.

```
$data['test'] = set_value('test');
```

You can use the set_value() in the controller, model, and view

Please use this script instead

```
function test() 
{
   $data = array('test' => NULL);
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('test', '', 'trim|xss_clean|required');
  if ($this->form_validation->run()) {
    $data['test'] = set_value('test');
  }
  $data['result'] = array('valuebydatabase' => 'lorem');
  $this->load->view('test', $data);
 }
```